# How to create empty media objects so that no exception will be thrown?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a music player app in Java that plays songs from playlist.

```
Media playlist[]  = new Media[1000];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
        playlist[i]=new Media(""); // this line
```

The playlist is loaded with songs with a method:

```
public void addSongToPlaylist(File file){     
    playlist[count] = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    count++;         
}
```

When I run my program, this exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == ''
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:211)
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
at musicplayerapp.MusicPlayerGUI.<init>(MusicPlayerGUI.java:32)
at musicplayerapp.MusicPlayerApp.main(MusicPlayerApp.java:25)
```

My question is: How can I initialize the array named Playlist with empty Media objects in such a way that no exception is thrown? Or can you suggest a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "empty Media" object. If you're concerned about `null`s, just use a `List` instead of an array:

```
private List<Media> playlist = new ArrayList<>();

public void addSongToPlaylist(File file){     
    playlist.add(new Media(file.toURI().toString()));
}
```